# how to retrieve Interactive Brokers historical data iteratively in Python?

Tags: python, iteration, trading, interactive-brokers

I am beginner of  Interactive Brokers native API user. Now, my trading system needs to retrieve Interactive Brokers  historical data iteratively like every one hour bar data . Now My problem is that the final data list append all of the once requested historical data even though the init configuration in the class of ibapi  is to be [].

it should download historical 60  1-minute bars in the first minute.  next minute, it is still so far 60 1-minute bars. next next minute, 60 bars. but the result is 60 bars. next minute , 120 bars. next next minute, 180 bars. it append all the once request historical data

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import datetime
import threading
import time
import pandas
from ibapi.order import Order
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data =[]# Initialize variable to store candle

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print(f'DateTime: {bar.date}  Open: {bar.open}  High: {bar.high} Close: {bar.close}  Low: {bar.low}  Volume: {bar.volume}')
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.open,bar.high,bar.close,bar.low,bar.volume])

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

# Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1)  # Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

# Create contract object
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = 'N225M'
contract.secType = 'FUT'
contract.exchange = 'OSE.JPN'
contract.currency = 'JPY'
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = '202310'


starttime = time.time()
timeout = time.time() + 60*60*6
while (time.time() <= timeout ):

    if (datetime.datetime.now().minute % 1==0 )and (datetime.datetime.now().second<10):
        app.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, '', '3600 S', '1 min', 'TRADES', 0, 1, False, [])
        # 
        time.sleep(2)  # sleep to allow enough time for data to be returned
        # headers = ['DateTime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close','Volume']
        # print(dict(zip(headers, app.data)))
        # df_data = {}
        df = pandas.DataFrame(app.data)
        df.columns=['DateTime','Open','High','Close','Low','Volume']
        # df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].dt.tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai')
        print( len(df))
        print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear `self.data` when the request is finished, write a method for `historicalDataEnd`:

```
def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):
    self.data = []
```